How can I add a scale animation to a background-attachment:fixed element?
I am trying to make an element that :

has the background-attachment: fixed attribute, so when you scroll it does not scroll with you ;
have a beautifull scale-out animation that runs once.

My problem is that both does not seem to be compatible.

When I use the scale or transform: scale(...) properties, the background-attachment property gets broken.
When I use the width and height properties, it does not seem to change the position and size of the image, so there is not any animation, because the image gets only cropped.
I've found for a lot of pages, but I couldn't find any dealing with that on stackoverflow, except some couples of unanswered questions.

There is my css code (exemple with "scale"):
main div.full-banner
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: var(--main-full-banner-padding);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--main-full-banner-shadow-size) var(--main-full-banner-shadow-color);
}

div.full-banner div.banner-background
{
    position: absolute;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('...');
    top: -1%;
    left: -1%;
    
    width: 102%;
    height: 102%;

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    animation: full-banner-zoom 60s ease-out;
}

@keyframes full-banner-zoom {
    from {
        scale: 120%;
    }

    to {
        scale: 100%;
    }
}

main div.full-banner div.banner-content
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}



And there is an example of how to use it :
<div class='full-banner'>
    <div class='banner-background'>
    </div>
    <div class='banner-content'>
        <h2>Hello world!</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>
</div>

How can I allow the background to at the same time have background-attachment: fixed and a animation on its scale?

You may need to be aware that IOS Safari struggles with background-attachment fixed. Consider putting the background on to a fixed pseudo element instead and scaling that.

When you're speaking about a pseudo-element, does it mean that it could also be a good idea to use an  element instead of using the background?

Matter of opinion, but I would always try to avoid adding elements to the DOM if they are just for visual effect.

I meet an issue there, because the fixed element cannot be cropped with the overflow:hidden property on its parent

One of the way of doing this is seprating image with div using ::before. Make the position:fixed and set top bottom left right to 0,then add background properties and at last use z-index then make your animation.


body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

main div.full-banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;         overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div.full-banner::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed; /* Keep the background fixed */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url('https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/183603772?v=4');
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1; 
    opacity: 0.8; 
    
    transform: scale(0); 
    transform-origin: center;
    animation: scale-out-image 5s forwards; 
}

div.full-banner div.banner-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    transform: scale(0); 
    animation: scale-out 2s forwards; 
  height:1000vh;
}

@keyframes scale-out {
    to {
        transform: scale(1); 
    }
}

@keyframes scale-out-image{
    to {
          transform: scale(1); 
    }
}
<div class='full-banner'>
    <div class='banner-content'>
        <h2>Hello world!</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>
</div>



Hope this helps...

Thanks a lot, BUT I wanted to use the scale out transition on the banner-background element :/

If that's the issue try using background-size in % default 100%

I tried it, but I need to use "cover", else the image size can be repeated or cropped depending on the devices. And using viewport sizes would not keep the image ratio.

@Kaki In I have edited the post try run snippet. I just first transform to 0 and set origin to center then I scale it up to 1. Hope this helps

@Jayiash Godani It does not work with background-attachment: fixed, the background-attachment is broken then.

@Jayish Godani it is what I have written at the first point of three in my question.

Can you provide an website example or video

https://tests-and-previews.flopcreation.fr/html/20241011/ . I set the transition duration for 4s, so you can see that the fixed background attachment does not work when the scale transform is set, and after the animation, the background attachment works.

See this I have added the height and time to animation so you can see it is working try directly using this code then add what you want

Now the problem is that the background is not removed outside the full-banner...

https://tests-and-previews.flopcreation.fr/html/20241011/v3/ ; I don't have the overflow:hidden anymore now... and you should also replace z-index:1 by z-index: -1
